# xml jquery doesnt work on Chrome

Tags: xml

When i  open it in Chrome it doesnt work for some reason. Can someone help me ? On IE WORK FINE!!!!  I try to make  on header a simply jquery and work. I dont find what is the problem

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        type: "GET",
        url: "BatteriaXMLdata.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('ProgressBAR').each(function(){
              var name = $(this).text();
              $(document.body).append('ProgressBAR: ' + name);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

FULL CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar">

<script >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        type: "GET",
        url: "BatteriaXMLdata.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('ProgressBAR').each(function(){
                        var name = $(this).text();

                $(document.body).append('ProgressBAR: ' + name);
            });
        }
    });
});
    </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.s.
on head jquery work ...

```
 $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

i dont konw what i can make ...

Comment: Is there any error in console? Do you use 'localhost' here?

Comment: no one error, just dont work, white page. Yes im on localhost.

Comment: Would be great to also have the XML.

Answer (score 0):

As the snippet below works fine in chrome, I would say it's certainly a XML format problem:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar">

<script >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don\'t forget me this weekend!</body><ProgressBAR>Test 1</ProgressBAR></note>').find('ProgressBAR').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).text();

        $(document.body).append('ProgressBAR: ' + name);
    });
});
    </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<progressbar>Reminder</progressbar>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>       (i make good, after i try again, nothing happen, ONLY on chrome: chrome stay to work for 2second, before process the page, he make long time. Other browser open it ISTANT)

Comment: ii think that my chrome is bugged

Comment: XML is case sensitive, your `progressbar` tag is all lowercase.

Comment: Does the code work when you try to run the code snippet above ?